# Can't see to convert and format nvarchar to my required datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there is already a lot of Q&A on related topics but honestly I can't find a solution here.

I have a field *ReceivedDateTime* and it appears as

> 2018-07-01T14:26:38.387

I can convert to `datetime` with a `CAST` which is fine. But what I need is it as a `datetime` but without the sub seconds *i.e.*

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss

No matter what flavour of `CAST`, `CONVERT`, `SUBSTRING` I use I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-07-01T14:26:38.387', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

that will return the output in your desired format:

> 2018-07-01 14:26:38

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `DATE_FORMAT` function

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2018-07-01T14:26:38.387', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

it returns '01-07-2018 14:26:38'

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2018-07-01T14:26:38.387', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
```

It will returns '07/01/2018 14:26'

T know about more on [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT convert(varchar,sysdatetime(),103) + ' ' +substring( convert(varchar,convert(TIME,sysdatetime()) ) ,1, dbo.INSTR(convert(varchar,convert(TIME,sysdatetime() )),':',1,2)- 1 )